# Issue with Spring Cloud Function on AWS Lambda using Gradle

Tags: java, spring, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I am trying to run a Spring Cloud Function on AWS Lambda. I followed the [official sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-aws)
and tried to build it using the gradlew build command. However, I encountered the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.cloud.function.aws-lambda.packaging', version: '1.0.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.cloud.function.aws-lambda.packaging:org.springframework.cloud.function.aws-lambda.packaging.gradle.plugin:1.0.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenLocal(file:/C:/Users/a1501/.m2/repository/)
    maven(https://repo.spring.io/milestone)
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 18s
```

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Could anyone provide some guidance on what I should do to successfully build my project?

Thank you in advance for your help.